# Tool for checking time slots of a coach or a teacher

Tags: time-management

My son has many tutors; such as swimming, table tennis, English, ... Normally, there is one hour or one and a half hour class per week. The class time is not fixed and should be checked with the teacher each time. The tutor usually sends a message to me, saying such as "is your son available on Saturday at 16:30?". I need to reply to him by 'yes', 'no' or suggesting some other time. Then, he may need to confirm if my suggested time slot is OK for him. Each tutor has tens of students.

You can imagine that s/he will spend lots of time each week arranging time slots for each of their students. Besides wasting time on it, it's boring to arrange such time slots.
I've been looking for a tool which can help my friends, the teachers. In my mind, the tool would serve as:

1. a teacher can provide a timetable to mark his/her available time slot, so that the student can un/check his/her time slot, the time slot conflict won't happen.
2. each student can set some time slots as waiting so that when a checked slot is unchecked, s/he will be notified.
3. when a teacher updates his/her timetable, each student will be notified.
4. a teacher will be notified once the timetable was updated.
5. the timetable can be configured so that only one or two or ... time slots will be checked at one week or month, or unlimited.
6. ...
   That is, the communication between teachers and students will be thru a timetable at a web address. The time slot will be marked date and time.

I believe such kind of tool will serve as a good assistant for a teacher for managing time slots well and it helps not only teachers but also makes each student more comfortable to communicate with their teachers.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- [Easy!Appointments](https://easyappointments.org/): "a highly customizable web application that allows your customers to book appointments with you via the web." It is open source so can be self-hosted. Even though it says "Customers", it can be used for Teachers too.
- [See here](https://edgeryders.eu/t/list-open-source-software-for-resource-scheduling-and-booking/6629) for a list of other apps to explore e.g. BookedScheduler

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Schedule is available for free with many tiers of Office 365 subscriptions and does most of what you want.